# ::before and ::first-line don't work right correctly

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

MDN says:

> The ::first-line CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first line of a block-level element.

But when i write this:

```css
p::before {content: 'Red text'; display: block;}
p::first-line {color: red;}
```

```html
<p>This text shouldn't be red</p>
```

it doesn't work in Firefox (word 'Hello' isn't red). What's wrong with this one?

Comment: you can have `color:red` into `::before` instead, will work everywhere

Comment: Well, since there is no word "hello", I am not surprised that it's not red.

Comment: is it works in other browsers?, btw first guy suggest good option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's wrong with this one?

Simply put, there is no problem with this behavior. Firefox's behavior is also correct based on the specifications.

---

The behavior of the `::first-line` pseudo-element when the first line is the  `::before`, `::after` pseudo-element is selectively shown in the specification<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content)</sup>. So it's no wonder that all browsers don't behave consistently.

> ### § 4.1. Generated Content Pseudo-elements: ::before and ::after<sup>[[1]](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#generated-content)</sup>
>
> As with the content of regular elements, the generated content of `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements may be included in any `::first-line` and `::first-letter` pseudo-elements applied to its originating element.

Also, the behavior when applying the style is as written in Selectors Level 3, which matches the behavior of Google Chrome<sup>[[2]](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#gen-content)</sup>. And if you don't apply styles to the matching elements, it works like Firefox.

> #### 7.4. The ::before and ::after pseudo-elements<sup>[[2]](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#gen-content)</sup>
>
> The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements can be used to describe generated content before or after an element’s content. They are explained in CSS 2.1 [CSS21].
>
> When the `::first-letter` and `::first-line` pseudo-elements are applied to an element having content generated using `::before` or `::after`, they apply to the first letter or line of the element including the generated content.

As an example, Google Chrome and Firefox differ in whether the `::first-line` pseudo-element decoration is applied to the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

**Question code behavior in Google Chrome**

[image: It turns out that the part which hits the first line among the characters shown in the question sentence turns red.]

**Question code behavior in Firefox**

[image: It can be seen that the part corresponding to the first line of the characters shown in the question sentence is not red.]

---

To do the same with Google Chrome in Firefox, you can apply the `color` property to the `::before` pseudo-element, as [@Ravi wrote in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408341/before-and-first-line-dont-work-right-correctly#comment103160608_58408341) in the question text.

```css
p::before {
  content: 'Red text';
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>This text should be red</p>
```